# Estimating the number of colors in a bucket

Tags: probability

> This question has been cross-posted to MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200489/estimating-the-number-of-colors-in-a-bucket).

Suppose we have a bucket containing a large (but known) number of balls. Each of the balls has a color. We don't know how many colors there are, but given a ball of one color, we have an oracle which can tell us how many of the other balls also have that color. If we are allowed to repeatedly reach in, pick a ball, observe its color, and return it, how should  we estimate the number of colors in the bucket?

More precisely, suppose we are given $N$ samples $\{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_N\}$ from a uniform distribution on some finite set $S$. We know $|S|$, and are given, as black boxes,

- an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$, so that for any $s_i$ and $s_j$, we can check if $s_i \sim s_j$. (Take $\sim$ to be drawn from a uniform distribution over all equivalence relations on $S$.)
- a function $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$ where $f(s)$ computes the cardinality of the equivalence class of $s$.

Using these tools, how can we estimate the number of equivalence classes in $S / \sim$?

Comment: Not sure there is anything you can say other than that the number of colors is at least $1+C$, where $C$ is the number of colors in your sample, and at most $C+|S|-K$ where $K$ is the total of the equivalence classes of the colors you selected. Essentially, there is no probability measure on the space of possible number of colors.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see what you mean. What if we suppose that $\sim$ is drawn from a uniform distribution over all equivalence relations on $S$ (of which, for a fixed $|S|$, there are only finitely many)?

Comment: That might be doable. The set of partitions of $S$ is a notoriously complex Poset, but I don't know what could be said about such a probability.